# Vaadin UI Detached exception

Tags: vaadin

I am using Vaadin 7.7.10 and I see many `UIDetachedExceptions` in the logs while using background `Threads` and the `@Push` annotation.

Please suggest how to release the resources properly in order to clean my logs.

Comment: Please show some of your code relevant to this. Are you sure they are a problem at all and not only left over sessions from users?

Answer (score 5):

If you do something in `UI.access(..)` to the `UI` that has been already detached, you will trigger an `UIDetachedException`. This is natural, if for example user has closed the browser, or there has been something in the network that has closed the connection, and thus the `UI` has been detached. If in your case the `UIDetachedException` is happening due these reasons, it is harmless. In that case, you can avoid littering your log by checking `UI.isAttached()` which returns `false` if the `UI` has been detached, and `UI.isClosing()` if the `UI` has already been put into the clean-up queue.

Comment: There's one small gotcha with the approach suggested here. There's a small chance that the UI will become detached between the moment you run `ui.isAttached()` and `ui.access(handler)`. You would still get rid of most of the exceptions, but not all of them.

Comment: That is correct. However I haven't seen that happening in real life.

Comment: Is it also possible to perform cleanup in the very `Component` subclass by overriding `com.vaadin.flow.component.Component#onDetach`?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the user has closed their browser window or tab which means that the particular UI instance is no longer in use.

The best approach is usually to override the `detach` method in your application's UI subclass and do the cleanup there. Just remember to also call `super.detach()`.

Another alternative is to catch the `UIDetachedException` that may be thrown by `UI.access` and do the cleanup at that point. The drawback of this approach is that you don't get the notification immediately when the UI is detached, but only when trying to do something with it.

Note: In Vaadin 10 and newer, the name of the method is `onDetach` rather than `detach`. It's also not recommended to subclass `UI` in those versions but instead use the built-in implementation and use `addDetachListener`.